# How to retrieve the quaternion in (x,y,z,w) format from tf

Tags: quaternion, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When we use tf to retrieve the rotation relationship of two coordinate in quaternion form, according to the API of [Quaternion](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Quaternion.html), we can only get the rotation axis and its angle.

However, the commonly required quaternion in ROS, such as quaternion in geometry_msgs::Pose, is always in (x,y,z,w) format. Therefore, is there any function to get the quaternion from tf in (x,y,z,w) form? That will be very convienent.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107866/how-to-retrieve-the-quaternion-in-(x,y,z,w)-format-from-tf/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2013-12-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tf::Quaternion inherits from tf::QuadWord which has m_floats[0] through m_floats[3] which are x,y,z,w respectively. http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/tf/html/c++/QuadWord_8h_source.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-12-08**:
Thanks for that! It works fine and can be verified by the relationship between (x,y,z,w) and the rotation axis plus the angle returned by quaternion.getAxis() and quaternion.getAngle().

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-12-08**:
But I would like to ask how to find this information? It is not in the tutorial and it is not obviously written out in the documentation. Although I can trace the code to get this info, are there any better approach to learn it? Thanks very much

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-08**:
It should show in the doxygen docs better but for some reason it doesn't show the inheritance correctly.

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-12-10**:
Yeah, I expect to see the inheritance diagram too. Do you have any idea about how to deal with such condition? Thanks

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-10**:
It's something about how doxygen is configured.  If you want to dig into it you can checkout the package and run doxygen yourself. http://wiki.ros.org/rosdoc_lite has documentation about how to run the documentation like it is on the farm.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

m_floats is a protected variable. In stead access x,y,z,w through **quaternion.x()** etcetera.

---

Originally posted by [tobyhijzen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25974/tobyhijzen/) with karma: 86 on 2016-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hmchung](https://answers.ros.org/users/28696/hmchung/) on 2017-01-20**:
Worked for me, on ROS Indigo! Thanks!